# Создание REST API

Tags: php, mvc, rest

Нужно создать API для приложения iOS,чтобы оно могло обращаться к БД сайта. Сайт сделан в структуре MVC. Как впилить в него api, чтобы стиль MVC не нарушился? Я решил так: создал ApiController, и там создаю объект, к которому обращается клиент (iOS приложение) и вызываю запрашиваемый метод (выглядит примерно так api/*SIGNATURE*/users.getInfo?id=3) Где users - это объект, getInfo - метод, id - аргумент метода. Но не долго думая понял, что это не безопасно, т.к. у меня включена автоподгрузка классов, то получается можно вызвать любой класс, не обязательно API.

Как сделать, чтобы например вызывал только экземпляры базового класса API? Или вообще я не так делаю и нужно по другому? Если я всё-таки прав, то скажите пож-та ещё как мне можно сделать принятие аргументов динамичным, чтобы методы АПИ у меня принимали не массив, а прям так и принимали $id,$order,$limit к примеру.

Comment: да ничего особо менять не нужно, у вас таже схема, только выдача конента не в HTML, а в другом формате, делайте те же контроллеры, view которых будyт отдавать не html, а xml или json (ContentType header 'text/html' смените на 'text/xml' или 'application/json')

Comment: ну да так можно, но это типа не по стандарту)) вроде как

Comment: @mctrane ну чтобы было правильно добавте поддержку PUT, DELETE, остальное через router - GET /info/{id} вызывает контроллер к пр. DataController, протокол GET - значит будет допустим вызываться action 'getAction' c передачей ему id; в случае DELETE /info/{id}
вызывается тот же контроллер только action другой, скажем 'deleteAction' также с передачей ему id. Вьюшки в этих случаях могут отдавать скажем в xml формате результат действия. Чем плохо? :)
Остальное это правильно подобрать глаголы и тд, т.е. лирика